# spring multiple transaction manager issue

Tags: spring, transactions

I have two transaction manager defined in two separate spring xml file, and both of them loaded into spring context

File One

```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>

  <bean id="transactionManager1"
       class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    ...
  </bean>
```

File Two

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager2"/>
  <bean id="transactionManager2"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    ...
  </bean>
```

If I didn't indicate any qualifier for the below service, which transaction manager spring are going to use.

```
public class TransactionalService {

    @Transactional
    public void setSomething(String name) { ... }

    @Transactional
    public void doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Check out [*11.5.6 Using @Transactional*](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) from the official documentation:

> You can omit the `transaction-manager` attribute in the `<tx:annotation-driven/>` tag if the bean name of the `PlatformTransactionManager` that you want to wire in has the name `transactionManager`. If the `PlatformTransactionManager` bean that you want to dependency-inject has any other name, then you have to use the `transaction-manager` attribute explicitly [...]

Since none of yours transaction managers are named `transactionManager`, you must specify which transaction manager should be used for methods marked with `@Transactional`.

---

UPDATE: to address your modified question. You can specify which transaction manager to use on `@Transactional` annotation (see: [`@Transactional.value()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value%28%29)):

```
@Transactional("transactionManager1")
//...

@Transactional("transactionManager2")
//...
```

However I see several problems with your current setup:

- you define `<tx:annotation-driven/>` twice with different transaction managers. I don't think such configuration is valid
- without providing transaction manager explicitly, which one should be used?

The solution I think should work is to define `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager1"/>` once and use `@Transactional` to use first manager and `@Transactional("transactionManager2")` to use the second one. Or the other way around.

Comment: ok, I did some modification to my question, actually this is the issue what I am facing.

Comment: I need to define multiple `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="yourTxMgrName"/>` for multiple transaction managers, else Spring can't see my transaction managers.