# Working with Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and multiple transaction manager: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined

Tags: spring, hibernate, cxf, spring-data-jpa, transactionmanager

**EDIT**: to whoever may be in interested in this issue, I provide the analysys of the problem with the related solution at the end of the question.

I am configuring a module for a web application in which I am using Spring 3.2, Hibernate 4.1, Spring Data JPA 1.3 and Apache CXF 2.5 (in particular the JAX-RS module). I have the following configuration (which is working perfectly fine, detailed are omitted for sake of conciseness):

```
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    //...    
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws SQLException{
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    //...    
    return manager;
  }

  @Bean(name = "persistenceExceptionTranslator")
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslator getPersistenceExceptionTranslator(){
    return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
  }
```

My problem is that I have to rely on some external modules which define their own `PlatformTransactionManager`, so I find myself working with more transaction manager at the same time. This issue is easily addressed by [Transactional.html#value()](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#value%28%29), so wherever I need to use `@Transactional` I qualified the annotation with the name of the transaction manager I have to use for that transaction.
I would like to change the name of the transaction manager I define in my module to something more meaningful, to meet the standard of the external modules. So, e.g., `externalModule1` defines its manager as `externalModule1TransactionManager` and I would like to have

```
  @Bean(name = "myModuleransactionManager")
  public JpaTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws SQLException{
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    //...    
    return manager;
  }
```

This seems pretty easy, unfortunately when I do this change (and I change the usage of `@Transactional#value()` accordingly I get an exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:110)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:323)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:154)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:113)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.createFault(AbstractInvoker.java:155)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:167)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:94)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:278)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:246)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy98.save(Unknown Source)
    at myModule.package.SomeOtherClass.someOtherMethod(SomeOtherClass.java:114)
    at myModule.package.SomeOtherClass$$FastClassByCGLIB$$2bda5a73.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at myModule.package.SomeClass$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$37044080.myMethod(<generated>)
    at myModule.package.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
    ... 34 more
```

In particular, I would like to focus the attention on

```
myModule.package.SomeOtherClass.someOtherMethod(SomeClass.java:114)
```

and

```
myModule.package.SomeClass.someMethod(SomeClass.java:64)
```

Their codes look like

```
@Transactional("myModuleransactionManager")
public ... someOtherMethod(){
   ...
}
```

and

```
public ... someMethod(){
   ...
}
```

So, in my understanding this configuration should work, why does it throw that exception? Is a standard named transaction manager required? Or is it something due to cxf? I found some questions related to multiple transaction manager within the same application ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606257/spring-multiple-transaction-manager-issue), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719646/no-bean-named-transactionmanager-is-defined)) but the accepted answer in those questions drive to my solution. What did I misunderstand and I am doing wrong?
Thanks to everybody who is willing to read this long question till here!

**EDIT to provide a complete explanation based on Michail's answer**: using [Spring Data JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) there is the need to define repositories interfaces to connect to the database. `someOtherMethod` is indeed calling one of my repositories which is defined as:

```
@Repository("myRepository")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NESTED, value = "myModuleransactionManager")
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>
{

}
```

This again looks fine, but looking at `JpaRepository` implementation source code (so, looking at `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository` I discovered that the `save` (as well as other update methods) is annotated with `@Transactional`. Code from `SimpleJpaRepository`

```
    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

Therefore, when using Spring Data JPA the default transaction manager (the one named `transactionManager`) is mandatory. Bad for my goal, but at least I now know that's it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like your `someOtherMethod` calls any other `@Transactional` component (some class with `save` method).  And I think it has `@Transactinal()` (empty) annotation (which uses default bean named `transactionManager`).

You may see 2 `TransactionInterceptor` positions in stacktrace. Please provide some details about it.

Comment: Michail, your answer drove me into the right direction to find the root cause of my problem. My configuration is perfectly fine, the problem resides in [Spring Data Jpa](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa). I extended your answer to provide the explanation of this statement.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you just need to ensure that your repositories use the correctly named transaction manager in your @EnableJpaRepositories annotation.

i.e.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "fooEntityManagerFactory", 
        transactionManagerRef = "fooTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.sctrcd.multidsdemo.integration.repositories.foo"})
public class FooConfig {
    //...
}
```

It took me a while to figure out the details, so I have just provided a fuller explanation of how to configure Spring Data JPA repositories to work with multiple datasources here:

[Multiple jpa:repositories in xml config, how to configure with @EnableJPARepositories using Spring java config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008809/multiple-jparepositories-in-xml-config-how-to-configure-with-enablejpareposit/19976132#19976132)

And a full project demonstrating it here:

https://github.com/gratiartis/multids-demo

Comment: I ended up using a single transaction manager (named `transactionManager` so Spring JPA is happy), with multiple datasources. In code terms, I used lots of abstract classes to define basic behaviors and specific configuration classes which extend the abstract ones. That said, if I can now figure out how I did that I may create a sample project on github to share my implementation. May be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way to use named TransactionManager with Spring Data JPA.
This works for me:

```
<bean id="myTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEntityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.xxx.yyy" entity-manager-factory-ref="myEntityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="myTransactionManager">
</jpa:repositories>
```

Comment: The crucial part which I was missing is the `transaction-manager-ref="myTransactionManager"` on the `<jpa:repositories>` tag. It's neither necessary not enough to specify the transaction manager at the `<tx:annotation-driven>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found your question very interesting conceptully. And thus was able to revise some of my long forgotten concepts. Looks like its a limitation on java config side. So you will have to resort to a bit of xml in between and then giv **transactionmanager** something like

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myModuletransactionManager"/>
```

then you can give use your transactionManager. Default **SimpleJpaRepository**
will also use the new one only.

**Update:** Or by the way you can use this through Config also now it seems [EnableTransactionManagement](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html)

Comment: I already have my Spring configuration class annotated with `@EnableTransactionManagement`,which doesn't help. Moreover, source code of `SimpleJpaRepository` clearly use `@Transaction`. Spring documentation states: `You can omit the transaction-manager attribute in the <tx:annotation-driven/> tag if the bean name of the PlatformTransactionManager that you want to wire in has the name transactionManager. If the PlatformTransactionManager bean that you want to dependency-inject has any other name, then you have to use the transaction-manager attribute explicitly, as in the preceding example.`

Comment: Thus, when `@Transaction` is used without the value attribute I understand there is no way to use other than the standard named transactionManager. I now moved on and have some stuff to do, but as soon as I'll commit such stuff, I'll have a small idea I want to try! Probably already later today. Then, I will eventually update this thread.

Comment: No, that is for overriding default transactionManager bean name only, I believe

Comment: Yep, that `<tx:annotation-driven />` is used to override the default name. On the other hand, however, `@Transaction` is equivalent to `@Transaction("transactionManager")`, that is why if I change the default name then `SimpleJpaRepository` stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I have qualified @Transactional at my service layer. And it seems to me that we can disable transaction management in Spring Data repository as following:

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="ru.xdsoft.conn.thanksapp.thanks.dao.repository"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="thanksEntityManagerFactory"
                  enable-default-transactions="false"
/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="ru.xdsoft.conn.thanksapp.orgstruct.dao"
                  entity-manager-factory-ref="orgStructEntityManagerFactory"
                  enable-default-transactions="false"
/>
```

Not sure by 100% but error is gone. Found it here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/resources/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/disable-default-transactions.xml

Answer (score 0):

I've done it a couple of times, so here's how to do it completely in Java code (no xml). I do use Lombok however, which I highly recommend. I focus solely upon the asked problem, so if you've never done this before, read the Spring docs for configuring additional details concerning JPA dialects and spring datasource driver-classes.

Explanation: when calling the JPA embedded methods like `findAll()` or `save()` the TransactionInterceptor will look for the default `"transactionManager"`
Here's what you need **to connect multiple databases through Hibernate and JPA**.

1. Define your variables in the `application.properties`

```
first.datasource.url=my/database/url/example
first.datasource.username=username-example
first.datasource.password=password-example

second.datasource.url=my/database/url/example
second.datasource.username=username-example
second.datasource.password=password-example
```

2. Create your databaseConfig

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "firstEntityManagerFactory", basePackages = {
        "be.company.appname.repository.firstdatabase", "be.company.appname.config.firstdatabase"
})
public class FirstDatabaseConfig {

    @Value("${first.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${first.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${first.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    private String driver;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties("first.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("first.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource dataSource(@Qualifier("firstDataSourceProperties") DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setRemoveAbandonedOnMaintenance(true);
        dataSource.setInitialSize(10);
        dataSource.setMaxTotal(20);
        dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1 from MY_SCHEMA.TABLE");
        dataSource.setValidationQueryTimeout(900_000);
        dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        dataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
        dataSource.setTestOnReturn(true);
        dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("firstDataSource") DataSource firstDataSource
    ) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(firstDataSource)
                .packages("be.company.appname.model.firstdatabase")
                .persistenceUnit("first")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "firstTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("firstEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory firstEntityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(firstEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

A few notes on this:

- notice the `@Primary`! You'll only need this on **1 of the databaseConfigs**! For your second database, you can use the same code and make the obvious changes, including the namechanges (e.g. firstEntityManagerFactory becomes secondEntityManagerFactory etc.), changing the appropriate variables, changing the ValidationQuery and defining the correct packages.
- in the second databaseConfig, I removed `"be.company.appname.config.firstdatabase"` from the `basePackages = {}` declaration. Only the pointer to the repository package will do.

3. Create your databaseObject in the package you defined within the `firstEntityManagerFactory` bean.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "UID")
    private String uid;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
```

- `@Table` is the exact name of your databasetable
- `@Column` is the exact name of your databasetable-column. Your own field-variables don't have to match, but I do it out of habit (e.g. declaring `@Column(name = "USERNAME") private String name;`
  would also work

4. Create your repository in the package you declared in the databaseConfig class

```
@Repository
@Transactional(value = "firstTransactionManager")
public interface MyUserRepository extends JpaRepository<MyUser, Long> {

    List<MyUser> findAll();
}
```

What causes the asker's exception to appear? For example:

I call `MyUserRepository.findById(1L)` without the method being declared in my repository. It is a known shorthand of JPA default embedded. Take a look at the details for your own [JPA shorthand queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).
If not declared in the repository, your application will look for the default `transactionManager` bypassing your repository-interface. But by declaring the method, your application will know to look for your own custom `firstTransactionManager`

**note:** The creation of the `BasicDataSource` may vary upon which database you're using. I'm using the `DB2Dialect`for connection to an AS400.