# @Transactional amongst spring-servlet.xml and application-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, transactional

In our web application we have many contextes. In one of them `tx:annotation-driven` is enabled. As result I have possibility to use `@Transactional` annotation around the project, except beans created and scanned (@Controller, and related @Service, @Component, etc..) in `spring-servlet.xml` (for one servlet's app context as was disscussed in [Difference between applicationContext.xml and spring-servlet.xml in Spring Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652090/difference-between-applicationcontext-xml-and-spring-servlet-xml-in-spring)).

My goals is to additionally enable this feature for beans related to `spring-servlet.xml`. I can try to do this with adding `tx:annotation-driven`, but based on this topic [spring multiple transaction manager issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606257/spring-multiple-transaction-manager-issue) such configuration considered not valid.

Could someone suggest in which way I can enable `@Transactional` for beans from `spring-servlet.xml`

Comment: Why not just annotate the classes you want to be transactional with @Transactional?

Comment: @WeareBorg The OP is doing that. The question is how to enable that annotation for multiple contexts in the same application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether I properly understand your setup but I assume that you have have a spring web application with multiple servlets; each servlet has it's own spring context and they all have the same parent spring context in common: `application-context.xml`.

If this is your setup, you should define your `PlatformTransactionManager` once in `application-context.xml`; as it's defined in the parent context it's automatically available in every servlet spring context. Then you should be able to use `tx:annotation-driven` in every servlet spring context and in the parent context as well without any problems as long as they use the same transaction manager.

It's not required to define a transaction manager in every context where you want to use `tx:annotation-driven`.